# can i use a name instead of a id in a request?

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm following an tutorial at angular.io (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-hero-by-id). I've been wondering if it's possible to use a name instead of id to send an request or is it premade and I always have to use id's and they have to be numbers?

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Hero>(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
  );
}
```

Comment: You can send whatever you want. But since the ID is what uniquely identifies a hero, sending it is the right, logical thing to do in this case, since the goal is to get the details of a specific, identified hero, and since that's what the backend expects. If you wanted to search all the heroes having a given name for example, you would send the name and get back an array of matching heroes.

Comment: It depends on what you're making requests to, different APIs will have different requirements. You may be able to search e.g. `/heroes?name={whatever}`.

Answer (score -1):

Its not specific to use Id's for sending requests, for particular Query String or Parameters.

Id's are preferred because they are  generated with unique code in our Back-ends.
Even the ids are mostly Number or integers which are easy to match conditions.
So, we prefer to use Id's instead of String Values .

If you have any more further doubts , please feel to elaborate your queries.

**Thanks !**